# How to sort nested dictionaries in TCL

Tags: tcl

I have a nested dictionary in TCL where the values at a particular index are unsorted at a subindex value, for example in this dictionary, I want to sort 55,21,36 and move the subkeys while sorting, and I also want to sort 103,344,3 while moving around their subkeys as well

I am very confused how one goes about doing something like this. I cannot use lsort -index -stride since my sub Dictionary isn't a single flattened list

```
a1,a2 {0,6 {103 55} 1,5 {344 21} 6,7 {3 36}}
```

Expected Output 1 [Sort based on 21,36,55 [final subvalues], 55 goes all the way towards the end with its key]

```
a1,a2 {1,5 {344 21} 6,7 {3 36} 0,6 {103 55}}
```

Expected Output 2 [Sort based on 344,3,103, 344 goes all the way towards the end along with its key]

```
a1,a2 {6,7 {3 36} 0,6 {103 55} 1,5 {344 21}}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Can you give different inputs and corresponding expected outputs after sorting, and any attempts you've had up to now?

Comment: Added in expected outputs, let me know if I wasn't super clear again

Comment: Ok, yes now it's clear. Did you try looking into the `-command` flag of `lsort`? It lets you define your own comparison proc. Otherwise, have you any attempts so far?

Comment: Sounds like deriving collation keys would be a way to go. You can tell `lsort` to give you the order that it found (ie., the derangement of the indices) and then use that to fix up the real data...